SO username requirement of being at least 3 characters long, doesn't fit very well the Chinese language

Possible Duplicate:
2 Character names? 

Chinese given names usually are 2 characters long, I don't think SO would make programming changes for a single site, but 2 character chinese names could also be used in other stack sites.

Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:  Display Name must be at least three characters


As you can see there is already a question covering the same ground. :) Voting to close as dupe.
